# gzip multiple files and rename them

Tags: files, gzip

I have to gzip multiple files in a directory and rename them.  I dont want to zip them into a single zip file. i.e.

gzip:

```
ABCDEPG01_20171120234905_59977
ABCDEPG02_20171120234905_59978
ABCDEPG03_20171120234905_59979
```

to:

```
ABCDEFG_DWH_ABCDEPG01_20171120234905_59977.gz
ABCDEFG_DWH_ABCDEPG02_20171120234905_59978.gz
ABCDEFG_DWH_ABCDEPG03_20171120234905_59979.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just adding a prefix? Then something like this could do:

```
prefix=ABCDEFG_DWH_
for f in ABCDEPG*; do
    gzip < "$f" > "$prefix$f.gz" && rm -- "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to [that of ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481999/116858) which only uses `gzip` ([as found on OpenBSD systems](https://man.openbsd.org/gzip.1) only):

```
for name in ABCDEPG*; do
    gzip -o "ABCDEFG_DWH_$name.gz" -- "$name"
done
```

Or in parallel with `xargs` (here, four parallel tasks will be spawned):

```
printf '%s\n' ABCDEPG* | xargs -P 4 -I {} gzip -o ABCDEFG_DWH_{}.gz -- {}
```

That parallel `xargs` thing for less advanced implementations of `gzip` (this would work on Linux):

```
printf '%s\n' ABCDEPG* |
xargs -P 4 -I {} \
    sh -c 'gzip -- "$1" && mv -- "$1.gz" "ABCDEFG_DWH_$1.gz"' sh {}
```

Comment: @don_crissti `/usr/bin/gzip` in the OpenBSD 6.4 base system. GNU systems doesn't have this!? Huh.  I'll make a note in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @don_crissti But, but, _everyone's_ using OpenBSD, suuurely?